# How to check if a Streamlit file upload is already present in an AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, streamlit

I am writing a Streamlit application which takes a file uploaded and sends it to an S3 bucket.
I have a classes.py file within the app which cleans the filename, and also puts the file uploaded through a number of checks.
I want to create a check which searches the files in an S3 bucket and compares it to the filename just uploaded. If they're the same (ie. if the file a user tries to upload is already present in the S3 folder), an error will crop up.

I have added the following code into the streamlit app to upload the file:

```
uploaded_files = st.file_uploader(label=f"Filename Goes Here", accept_multiple_files=True)
files_to_be_uploaded = []

if uploaded_files != []:

    # Get file name
    for file in uploaded_files:

        backing_data_details = BackingDataClass(file_name=file.name, uploaded_file=file)
        backing_data_details.process_backingdata()
        if backing_data_details.error is None:
            files_to_be_uploaded.append(backing_data_details)
            st.success(f"{file.name} parsing is successful")
        else: 
            st.error(f"{file.name} not parsed: {invoice_details.error}")

st.write(backing_data_details.df)

upload_successful = []
upload_failed = []


def upload_to_s3(upload_successful, upload_failed): 
    for file in files_to_be_uploaded:
        try:
            file.save_summary_to_s3(file.summary_df)
            file.save_backing_data_to_s3(file.df)
            upload_successful.append(file)
        except:
            upload_failed.append(file)

if st.button('Upload parsed files to S3', on_click=upload_to_s3(upload_successful, upload_failed)):
    for file in upload_successful:
        st.success(f'{file.file_name} upload successful')
    for file in upload_failed:
        st.error(f'{file.file_name} upload failed')
```

I'm not sure how I would then go about comparing a file uploaded to the filenames in a specific S3 bucket. How can I add this check in?
Thank you for your time.

I tried the following code as a check in the classes.py file, however, this only works for comparing files within an S3 bucket rather than comparing an uploaded file to the S3 bucket.

```
import boto3
import hashlib

def find_duplicate_files(bucket_name):
  # Create an S3 client
  s3 = boto3.client('s3')

  # Retrieve a list of objects from the bucket
  objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)

  # Create a dictionary to store the checksums
  checksums = {}

  # Iterate through the objects
  for obj in objects['Contents']:

    # Download the object and compute its checksum
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=obj['Key'])

    data = response['Body'].read()
    checksum = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()

    # Add the checksum to the dictionary
    if checksum in checksums
      # If the checksum already exists in the dictionary, it's a duplicate
      print(f'Duplicate file: {obj["Key"]}')
    else:
      checksums[checksum] = obj['Key']
  print('Done')
```